# TeX Live portable installation not shown after installed

Tags: texlive

I am trying to install TeX Live 2016 onto my USB drive. While I have chosen the

- install at the directory of my USB drive
- option of portable install

while at the interface. The folder did not appear after I have installed.

Did I do something wrong here?

Comment: what happen if you try reinstall?

Comment: I reinstalled the whole TeX Live 2016 and now I couldn't do my compilation on my desktop =(

Comment: @touhami I forgot to re-link everything back to the folder of TeX Live.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comment.